# Angular 2 "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.6"

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got router paths configured as following:

```
export const ROUTER_CONFIG: RouterConfig = [{
  path: '/',
  component: QtHomePageComponent,
}, {
  path: '/account',
  component: QtAccountPageComponent,
  children: [{
    path: '/dashboard',
    component: QtDashboardPageComponent,
  }],
}, {
  path: '/user',
  component: QtUserPageComponent,
  children: [{
    path: '/signin',
    component: QtUserSigninPageComponent,
  }, {
    path: '/signup',
    component: QtUserSignupPageComponent,
  }],
}];
```

Each "parent" component contains primary `<router-outlet>`.

When I'm navigating from `/` to `/user/signin` or `/user/signin` to `/user/signup` everything works fine, but when I'm trying to access `/account/dashboard` from `/user/signup` or any path with changed "parent" container it crashes with `browser_adapter.js:77 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '_routeConfig' of null` and it doesn't matter it is `this.router.navigate()` or `[routerLink]=""`.

Maybe anyone knows is it issue or I'm doing something wrong?

Full source: https://github.com/rtbm/ng2-app/tree/master/src

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/angular/vladivostok/issues/48